# Merge databases with similar but not identical tables into one MasterDB

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, merge

What's the best way (SQL-code or program) to merge multiple databases into one MasterDB with different but similar tables/views and columns?

Just tables and views, not data. Also set relations if there's any.

Example:

```
DB1    +    DB2   +    DB3        =         MasterDB

User        User       User                 User
 Id          Id         Id                   Id
 Name        Name       Name                 Name
 Address     City       Email                Address
                                             City
Posts       Posts      Comments              Email
 Id          Id         Id
 Title       Content    Title               Posts 
                                             Id  
                                             Title
                                             Content

                                            Comments
                                             Id
                                             Title
```

Comment: There is no "best" way. What tools do you have at hand? What have you tried yet? Do these structures change on a regular base? What are the exact DB engines?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server here? I assume the answer to your question is product specific!

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio. Have tried to create a SQL script using sp_msforeachdb but failed. When working on different but similar projects this could be a stored procedure run at nights.

Comment: Best way to write your own script if you want to run your code in jobs at night.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying you are using SQL Server Management Studio:

In Management Studio, rightclick on each database, select Tasks>Generate Scripts... . Go through the wizard, on Set Scripting Options you may wish to turn off the USE clause and make sure all relevant objects are scripted (triggers are not by default). Run the resulting scripts against the MasterDB, review it and repeat.

This way you will have a script importing these particular databases in that particular database. Unfortunately this is not a script like sp_mseachdb 'Export ? to MasterDB'.

Comment: Great idea! I've try it. But it's hard to get it work because... first it has to check if the table/view exist... if not: create it... then check every column if they exist.... if not: create it... and so on... for every DBs.

Comment: Well, that is sad. Seems you may benefit from a database diff/patch tool. Maybe https://opendbiff.codeplex.com/ or http://www.liquibase.org/ ? Unfortunately I have so limited experience with such tools that this comment could well be considered offtopic.

Comment: Ok, I'll will give it a try. Thanks for your help anyway.